# vb.net: clearing contents of System.Collections.ArrayList?

Tags: vb.net

how do i clear all elements in an arraylist?

Comment: Assuming .Net 2.0 or later, don't use ArrayLists!!

Comment: Because they're mostly just still in the framework for compatibility with previous versions.  System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T) almost completely replaces the ArrayList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call

```
arrayList.Clear()
```

Where `arrayList` is your ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim myAL As New ArrayList()
myAl.Clear()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.clear.aspx

Also.. With respect to Joel's comment...

[Drawbacks of ArrayLists](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/Saurabh.Mishra/GenericsInC2PartI11222006233239PM/GenericsInC2PartI.aspx)